# Mongo: how to covert a string to decimal?

Tags: mongodb, type-conversion, decimal

I have written millions of documents with $CURRENT_CASH_BALANCE as strings instead of decimals.  How can I convert them all to decimals?

Comment: 'code'
db.TESTHOLDINGS.find({CURRENT_CASH_BALANCE: {$type: "string"}}).forEach(function(obj) { 
obj.CURRENT_CASH_BALANCE = new NumberDecimal128(obj.CURRENT_CASH_BALANCE);
db.db-name.save(obj); });   this fails on NumberDecimal128.  I saw an example  withNumberInt that supposedly worked.  NumberDecimal also fails.

Comment: What is the MongoDB version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a collection with documents:

```
{ _id: 1, bal: "123.45" }
{ _id: 2, bal: "67890"}
{ _id: 3, bal: 999 }
```

The following command can be run from the `mongo` shell to update the two documents with the field `bal` canverted from *string* data type to [NumberDecimal](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/index.html#numberdecimal):

```
db.collection.find( { bal: { $type: "string" } }
).forEach( doc => { doc.bal = NumberDecimal(doc.bal); db.collection.updateOne( { _id: doc._id }, { $set: { bal: doc.bal } } ); } )
```

After the update, the documents:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "bal" : NumberDecimal("123.45") }
{ "_id" : 2, "bal" : NumberDecimal("67890") }
{ "_id" : 3, "bal" : 999 }
```